# Visual studio code not warning when Function constructor identifier used instead of a function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual studio code. As I understand JS is a case-sensitive language, so mistakenly typing 'Function' instead of 'function' a warning something like "eval harmful" and "missing semicolon" should have been shown. But why Visual studio code didn't give me any warning?

```
var laugh = Function(n)
{
   // my code 
};


var laugh = function(n)
{
    // my code 
};
```

Comment: Well, `function` is yellow, while `Function` is green

Comment: `Function` is a built-in type and `{...}` are valid in inline script so what you have is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can add some sugar in it

using pluging like **jshint** or **jslint** cant help you a lot. If you do not know how look at [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery)

**My favorite** is [quokka.js](https://quokkajs.com/)  it is an amazing tool for running your code immediately.

By the way the you put you "{" remind me a great [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY) from Douglas Crockford.
In some case putting your "{" left can bring bad surprise. So don't do it.

For Example

```js
var notReturnAnObject= function()
{
    return 
    {
        error:"bad"
    }
}

var notWhatYouThink= notReturnAnObject();

console.log(notWhatYouThink);
```

What is happenning is that the compiler put the semicolon for you

```
var notReturnAnObject= function()
    {
        return ;
        {
            error:"bad"
        }
    }
```

Instead do it like this and everything will be always fine

```js
var notReturnAnObject= function(){
        return {
            error:"bad"
        };
    }

var notWhatYouThink= notReturnAnObject();

console.log(notWhatYouThink);
```

And don't forget our semicolon ;)